Python error: model adapter API call error: pyodbc.OperationalError '[08004] (-1036) (SQLDriverConnect)
I am running a model adapter through an app. After activating the app, I am attempting to test the API calls. The first API test run is working properly. Testing the API calls the second time (keeping the app active) is throwing errors. The error is in one of the intermediate calls where the adapter is attempting to connect to an access database.
This API call works in the following way:

Description:
Call to retrieve the status of the model

Returns:

model_run_id

model state: ACCEPTED, PENDING, QUEUED, RUNNING, SUCCEEDED, ERROR

reason: description in case of state ERROR




The API call is coded as below:
@api.route("/status/<model_run_id>")
class Status(MethodView):

    @api.response(200, ModelRunInfo.Schema())
    def get(self, model_run_id: str):
        res = opera.status(model_run_id=model_run_id)
        return jsonify(res)

The API calls the following method within the adapter (Let's call this Model_X wrapping model_Y):
class Model_X(Model_Y):
..
..
..
    def status(self, model_run_id: str):
        try:
            if model_run_id in self.model_run_dict:
                if not executor.futures.done(model_run_id):
                    return ModelRunInfo(
                        state=self.model_run_dict[model_run_id].state,
                        model_run_id=model_run_id,
                        reason=f"executor.futures._state: {executor.futures._state(model_run_id)}"
                    )
                else:
                    #print("executor.futures._state: ", executor.futures._state(model_run_id))   # FINISHED
                    future = executor.futures.pop(model_run_id)
                    executor.futures.add(model_run_id, future)   # Put it back on again, so it can be retreived in results
                    model_run_info = future.result()
                    if model_run_info.result is not None:
                        print('Model execution result:', model_run_info.result)
                    else:
                        logger.warning("No result in model_run_info variable")
                    return model_run_info
            else:
                return ModelRunInfo(
                    model_run_id=model_run_id,
                    state=ModelState.ERROR,
                    reason="Error in Model_X.status(): model_run_id unknown"
                )
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'Exception in status method: {str(e)}')
            return ModelRunInfo(
                model_run_id=model_run_id,
                state=ModelState.ERROR,
                reason=f"Exception: {str(e)}"
        )

Within the Model_Y, the same method is defined as follows:
class Model_Y:
..
..
..
    def status(self, model_run_id: str):
        if model_run_id in self.model_run_dict:
            # Dummy behaviour: Query status once, to let finish model
            self.model_run_dict[model_run_id].state = ModelState.SUCCEEDED

            return ModelRunInfo(
                state=self.model_run_dict[model_run_id].state,
                model_run_id=model_run_id,
            )
        else:
            return ModelRunInfo(
                model_run_id=model_run_id,
                state=ModelState.ERROR,
                reason="Error in Model.status(): model_run_id unknown"
            )


The method to connect to the Microsoft Access Driver is coded below:
import sqlalchemy as sa
.
.
class AccessImporter:
..
..
..
    def connect_to_access(self, access_file: str):
        try:
            #access_file = r'C:\data\git\aimms-adapter\esdl2opera_access\Opties_mmvib.mdb'
            odbc_string = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + access_file + ';'

            print(f"Connecting to database {access_file}")
            connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
                "access+pyodbc",
                query={"odbc_connect": odbc_string}
            )
            self.engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
            self.engine.connect()
            self.conn = self.engine.raw_connection()
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Connecting to Access Error: {e}")

The method to disconnect Access is coded below:
Import gc
.
.
class AccessImporter:
..
..
..
    def disconnect(self):
        log.info("Disconnecting database")
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
        garbage_collected = gc.collect()
        log.info(f'amount of garbage collected is {garbage_collected}')

The short description of the error is as follows:
OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08004', '[08004] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too many client tasks. (-1036) (SQLDriverConnect)')\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)"
I have attempted to look into stack overflow to find similar issues. However, I find that my connection uses a different package. I have also followed the link in the error description. However, I still keep on getting the same error.
I intend to run the API calls without any issues as the app is supposed to always run in the background. Currently, I have to stop the app completely and restart it again and again to not get errors in the test API runs.
FYI: I did not create this app or the API calls. I am a user of the model adapter.
Other relevant information:
My environment has both 32 and 64-bit Microsoft Access drivers, with 64-bit installed. Both the model and the adapter are hosted in my own environment. When I tested the connect_to_access and disconnect methods (i.e., without involving API calls), I did not get any errors.
The model is AIMMS-based which need to use the Access Database (so the corresponding driver). So, I cannot move to other robust databases such as PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc.
My environment set-up:

SQLAlchemy version: 2.0.34
Python version: 3.11.5
MySQL version: 8.0.0

Major edits/updates since last posted:

added @contextmanager to the class AccessImporter. See the corresponding update:

from contextlib import contextmanager
..
class AccessImporter:
..
..
    def __enter__(self):
        """
        Enter the context: this is automatically called when using 'with'.
        """
        return self  # Return the instance itself to allow access to methods
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """
        Exit the context: this is automatically called when leaving 'with'.
        It ensures the connection is closed even in case of an exception.
        """
        self.disconnect()


The methods connect_to_access and disconnect are updated as well (also linking to @contextmanager). See below:

class AccessImporter: 
..
..
    @contextmanager
    def connect_to_access(self, access_file: str):
        #access_file = r'C:\data\git\aimms-adapter\esdl2opera_access\Opties_mmvib.mdb'
        odbc_string = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=' + access_file + ';Pooling=False;'

        log.info(f"Connecting to database: {access_file}")
        
        connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
        "access+pyodbc",
        query={"odbc_connect": odbc_string}
        )
            
        try:    
            # Create an engine for the database connection
            # Disable connection pooling by setting poolclass to NullPool
            self.engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url, poolclass=NullPool)

            # Connect to the engine
            self.conn = self.engine.raw_connection() # Raw DBAPI connection
            log.info("Connection to the database established.")

            #Create a cursor
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            log.info("Cursor created successfully.")

            yield # Yield control to the block of code that uses this context manager
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to the Access database: {e}")
            raise # Raising the exception so that the caller can handle it

class AccessImporter:
..
    def disconnect(self): 
        log.info("Disconnecting database")
        try:
            if self.cursor:
                log.info(f"Closing cursor: {self.cursor}")
                self.cursor.close()
                self.cursor = None
                log.info("Cursor closed successfully.")
            
            if self.conn:
                log.info(f"Closing connection: {self.conn}")
                self.conn.close() #Close the raw connection
                self.conn = None
                log.info("Raw connection closed successfully.")
            
            if self.engine:
                log.info(f"Disposing engine: {self.engine}")
                self.engine.dispose() # Dispose of the engine
                self.engine = None
                log.info("Engine disposed successfully.")

            # Pause to ensure all resources are freed
            time.sleep(3) # Give some time for cleanup

        except Exception as e: 
            log.error(f"Error during disconnect: {e}")
    
        # Optionally trigger garbage collection, but usually not necessary
        garbage_collected = gc.collect()
        log.info(f'amount of garbage collected is {garbage_collected}')

The method calling these functions to carry out the connections to the database is coded below (FYI: _create_energycarriers(), _add_activities(), etc. are just other methods called related to database activities before closing the connection):
class AccessImporter:
..
    def start_import(self, esdl_data_frame: pd.DataFrame, carriers: pd.DataFrame, access_database: str):
        """
        Connects to database file and uses esdl-dataframe to create opera database
        :param esdl_data_frame: dataframe extracting all relevant info for all the assets in the ESDL
        :param carriers: dataframe describing the carriers in the ESDL
        :param access_database: the path to the access database
        :return:
        """
        self.df = esdl_data_frame
        self.carriers = carriers
        is_consumer = self.df['category'] == 'Consumer'
        self.not_consumer_options = self.df[~is_consumer]
        self.consumer_options = self.df[is_consumer]

        #self.copy_clean_access_database()
        try:
            with self.connect_to_access(access_file=access_database):
                log.info("Database connection established and cursor created successfully")

                self._create_energycarriers()
                log.info("Created energy carriers successfully")

                self._add_activities()  # first activities, then options
                log.info("Added activities successfully")

                self._add_options()
                log.info("Added options successfully")
                
                self._update_option_related_tables()
                log.info("Updated options-related tables successfully")
        
        except Exception as e: 
            log.error(f"Failed to connect to the Access database: {e}")    


Hmm...I have never seen capital Import or Class used in Python.

Try disposing the sqlalchemy engine as well with cursors in disconnect call.

Roll back the connections if an error occurs.

@Parfait Now, disposed the sqlalchemy engine as well - see the updated disconnect method. Still I am getting the error. Thanks for the advice, though!
